# How can i test if a file write has succeeded in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any way to test if writing to a file was successfully accomplished? I need a method to obtain the end of time of a writing operation. If so to trigger a callback function.

Comment: `fwrite()` returns the number of bytes written, or `FALSE` on error.

Comment: How do you write in file? Show us your code, please. And as a short answer, yes, it is.

Comment: There's too many ways to answer this question. Show some code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error.

Check whether [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) returns false and you'll know that the write succeeded. Be careful to use the `===` comparison operator instead of the `==` operator when checking if the returned value is false.

You can use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to get the last modification time of a file.

Comment: Nice man - why don't you post opened PLB's comment as an extra answer? )))

Comment: @webbandit I don't follow what you mean

Comment: @Samuel eah sure you don't  ;)